# Is there a simple way to find the index of values in a array like select with index_of?

Tags: ruby

If I have an array of repeated values and I need to find the indexes of all the occurrence like

I tried with each_with_index but need something that is more efficient like select

```
arr = [2,3,4,3,5,6,3,7,8]   
# Now, I'm trying to grab the indexes of all the occurrences of 3

    final=[]
    arr.each_with_index do |x, i|
      final << i if x == 3
    end
```

In, Final I'm collecting all the indexes of 3's positions

the final array should have [1,3,6]

Comment: I will prefer `arr.length.times.select { |x| arr[x] == 3 }`

Comment: Hey Ray,  performance wise I see the each_index is taking less time to execute when comparing with length.times.

Comment: Yes agreed! `each_index` is better option.